# Function runs but never called using .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery

We accidentally forgot to execute an ajax_Sendmail() under sendmail function. But the function was fired up without being called. What seems to be the cause why the ajaxSendMail to run on its own.
Our flow:
 1. User types its details on the form
 2. The form validates to some inputs.
 3. If all is well send mail.
 4. Done.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        original_url_checker();
        create_site();
    });         

    //this will check if the template can build from your original url
    function original_url_checker(){
        var can_build = $("#can_build").val();  

            if(can_build == 'false'){
                /*$('#original_url').hide();*/
                $('#original_url').prop('disabled',true)
            }
            else{
                /*$('#original_url').show();*/
                $('#original_url').prop('disabled',false)
            }
    }//original checker

    //main function that will create site / sub account 
    function create_site(){
        $('#btn-create').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var ajax1 = ajax_Create();
            ajax1.done(sendMail).fail(failOption).always(alwaysOption);
            var template_id = $("#template_id").val();
            var original_url = $("#original_url").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            $('#inputHere').html('<ul><li>'+first_name+'</li><li>'+last_name+'</li><li>'+template_id+'</li><li>'+original_url+'</li><li>'+email+'</li></ul>');
            $(this).html('Creating Site');                  
    });
    }//create site
    function sendMail(data) {
        var dataa = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#btn-create').html('Sending Email');
        var c_email = dataa.ac;
        var c_fname = dataa.fn;
        var r_url = dataa.ru;
        var sso_link = dataa.sso;
        $('#btn-email').show();
        $('#ssoLink').html('<li><a href='+sso_link+'>SSO Link</a></li><li><a href='+r_url+'>Reset URL</a></li>');
    }   
    function ajax_Create(){
        return $.ajax({
        url:'create-site-con.php',
        method:'POST',
            data:"template_id="+template_id+"&original_url="+original_url+"&email="+email+"&first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name
            });
    }//ajax Create
    function ajax_Sendmail(){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
data:'first_name='+c_fname+'&reset_url='+r_url+'&email='+c_email+'&sso_link='+sso_link,
        success:function(response){
            var dataa = JSON.parse(response);
            var sso = dataa.sso;
            var status = dataa.f;
            if(status == "failed"){
                console.log('Failed');
                }
            else {
                 $('#btn-create').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#btn-create').html('Message Sent');
                console.log('Message Sent!');
                $('#ssoLink').html('<li><a href='+sso+'>SSO Link</a></li><li>'+status+'</li>');
                window.location.replace(sso,3000);  
                    }
                      }//success
                     });//ajax2
    }//ajax Sendmail

    function failOption(){
        console.log('Ajax Connection Failed');
        var btn = $('#btn-create');
        btn.html('Reload');
        btn.prop('disabled',false);
    }//fail 

    function alwaysOption(){
       console.log('I will do this no matter what');
    }//always
```

Comment: 1 - there is no `ajaxSendMail` function, so how can it be "running on it's own"? 2 - if you meant `ajax_Sendmail` function, it is never referenced in the code you posted, so also can not be "running on it's own" - perhaps some code you've omitted holds the answer

Comment: Yes, it is the ajax_Sendmail() is what we are referring, it is in the script with an ajax to our sendmail.php

Comment: OK, so you meant `ajax_Sendmail` - you say `the function was fired up without being called` - that's not possible, as **in the code you've posted** there is no other reference to that function except where it is being delcared

Comment: Yea, that's what we are trying to figure out because we tested it live yesterday.